# When does JavaScript that is generated by GWT appear?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Well, it's really a very basic question. Say, I made some changes, but I don't see them without `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`, which is fine, as far as I know. When exactly do these changes appear in generated JavaScript? Could someone please provide an answer or a link to this lifecycle description? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke the GWT compiler. This may be using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, Maven, Ant or whatever build system you use.